# Stopping jQuery live from affecting chlidren

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DOM structure as follows:

```
<div class="hotspot">
    <div class="hotspot_inner">
        <div class="hotspot_info">
            <div class="inner_box">
                <h2><%= hotspot.info.title %></h2>
                <p><%= hotspot.info.description.html_safe %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have some CoffeeScript that attaches a click event listener to anything with the class '.hotspot' that makes everything inside the hotspot visible ('.hotspot_inner' and down) on click.

Clicking anything with the '.hotspot' class again makes everything inside invisible once more.

The problem is, clicking anything inside the hotspot also triggers the close event attached to its parent.

I've tried stopPropagation(), but to no avail. I've heard .live has issues like this, but because hotspots are added dynamically, I need to use it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to use it... `$(document).on("click", ".hotspot", function(){...});` Is the new standard. Ideally, you'd have a closer parent than document to use as the main selector.

Comment: tying delegations to the document is generally discouraged though as that's really high up the bubble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `stopPropagation()` won't work because the event has *already propagated*; that's how the "live" mechanism works.

What you can do instead is to set a flag somewhere, perhaps on the event object itself. The parent handlers can check for that and know that they're not supposed to do anything.

Alternatively, you could check the event target, which jQuery normalizes as the "target" property of the event object. If the parent handlers see that they're not the target, they can skip the event. This can get tricky sometimes depending on the nature of your interaction patterns and the structure of the DOM.

You may be interested to learn that `.live()` has been deprecated for a couple of years now. With current versions of the library you should use `.on()`, which combines the abilities of `.bind()` and `.delegate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Check event.target.

```
    if (event.target.className === 'hotspot') {
        // do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is: when you click .hotspot class you want anything inside to toggle, and if you click anything inside .hotspot_inner class(text or whatever), you do not want to trigger the click event on .hotspot? if that is the case, you should make sure stopPropagation() is inside .hotspot_inner click event.

```
    $('.hotspot_inner').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();

    })​
```

please have a look here if that is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/5JJEd/